# How to insert foreign keys into a table based on current user

Tags: postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy

I am building a web app in Flask-SQLAlchemy with 3 main types of users (carrier, broker, shipper) who can each access different parts of the site. I am wanting to connect employees and other components to their organizations through foreign keys. My tables look like this:

carrier_org:

```
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
org_name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
email = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
```

contact:

```
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
carrier_org = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('carrier_org.id'), 
                                                    nullable=False)
```

When the user signs up, it creates both a newUser and newCarrier object.
When I am signed in as a carrier, I have a method addContact that looks like this:

```
@app.route('/add_contact', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
@required_roles('carrier')
@login_required
def addContact():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f_name = request.form['f_name']
        l_name = request.form['l_name']
        title = request.form['title']
        phone = request.form['phone']
        email = request.form['email']
        newContact = contact(f_name = f_name, l_name = l_name, phone = phone, email = email, title = 
                     title)
        db.session.add(newContact)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('carrierProfile'))
    return render_template('addContact.html')
```

My question is this: How do I insert a carrier_org FK into contact to be able to track which organization employees belong to? I was thinking something along the lines of

```
carrier_id = ("SELECT carrier_org.id FROM carrier_org, users WHERE carrier_org.email = users.current_user.id")
```

Then my newContact will be

```
newContact = contact(carrier_id = carrier_id, f_name = f_name, l_name = l_name, phone = phone, email = email, title = 
                     title)
```

But I am not sure how to tie this all together.

Comment: Can you add the relevant parts of your `contact` and `carrier_org` models.

Comment: Those were the tables, but yes, I have replaced it with relevant info in models.py